# linq - from in select

Tags: c#, linq

I'm making a small example to understand about `from in select`.

My example:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<Person>();
        list.Add(new Person(name: "Hermione", age: 20));

        var persons = from p in list select new { p.Age, p.Name };            
        foreach (var person in persons)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {person.Name}. Age: {person.Age}");
        }

        var _persons = from p in list select new Person(p.Name, p.Age);
        foreach (var person in _persons)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {person.Name}. Age: {person.Age}");
        }
    }
}
```

Both of them have same result:

> Name: Hermione. Age: 20

My question: what's the difference betweeen the first and the second? And when to use the first/second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all here is anonymous type `var persons = from p in list select new { p.Age, p.Name };` So you can make random names of properties for example

```
 var persons = from p in list select new { AgesSomeWithDay = p.Age , FullName = p.Name + p.Name };
```

**BUT**  `var _persons = from p in list select new Person( p.Name, p.Age);`
is strongly typed you can't make random named properties because here is `new Person`and `Person` class contains two properties which you only and can assign to _persons

Answer (score 3):

`var persons = from p in list select new { p.Age, p.Name };`  - creates anonymous type

`var _persons = from p in list select new Person(p.Name, p.Age);` - creates Person

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

> Anonymous types typically are used in the select clause of a query
>   expression to return a subset of the properties from each object in
>   the source sequence.
>
> Anonymous types contain one or more public read-only properties. No
>   other kinds of class members, such as methods or events, are valid.
>   The expression that is used to initialize a property cannot be null,
>   an anonymous function, or a pointer type.
>
> Anonymous types are class types that derive directly from object, and
>   that cannot be cast to any type except object.

Comment: If the OP really want to understand this, download a tool like [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), decompile the OP's little app, and look at the compiler generated code (with dotPeek you have to enable the compiler generated code).  This will *really* help visualize what you're trying to explain.